# Chart in LWC is not updating

Tags: lightning-web-components

my chart in LWC is not updating. The chart loads the first time but when I enter new data it does not update. Do I need to clear the data before I call this method?

```javascript
updateChart(data) {
    console.log(this.chartConfiguration)
    let chartData = [...data]
    let chartLabels = ["Principle ($)", "Interest($)"]

    this.chartConfiguration = {
        type: "doughnut",
        data: {
            labels: chartLabels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Mortgage Amount',
                    data: chartData,
                    backgroundColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        'rgb(75, 192, 192)',]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    position: "top"
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Chart.JS Doughnut Chart of Mortgage Amount"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your whole code, where you are modifying data and html component as well.

Comment: Hi @darkshadowrule, here is the link to code(everything): https://github.com/jsaparbekova31/mortgageCalculator

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is you are not rendering your chart component again when the data is changing.

Take a variable in mortgageCalJS and set it false once enter in update method then at the end of the method set it true.

```
//Update the chart
chartLoaded = false;
updateChart(data) {
   this.chartLoaded = false
      your code
    this.chartLoaded = true;
}
```

And in the html(mortgageCalcHTML)

```
<template if:true={chartLoaded}>
      <c-chart chart-config={chartConfiguration}></c-chart>
</template>
```

This will rerender your component every time data is updated and you will get updated chart.